# "went back" To extend in time in past tense

Tags: past-tense

Please check the sentences below:

> I found a post on that site that its date went back to 1999.

or I should rather say:

> I found a post on that site that was dated for 1999.

Which one is correct?

Comment: A simple tip for your future reference. *how does some date go back?* - its date *went* back... is not natural. *Dated back* means referring to some date back in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use either of the two.

These would sound better:

> I found a post on his site that dated back to 1999.
>   I found a post on his site that was dated 1999.

The second one still sounds off - because I would expect an actual date there:

> I found a post on his site that was dated April 1st 1999.

Alternatively, you can simply say:

> I found a post on his site from 1999.

Although you might get confused as to whether the site or the post are referred to.

> I found a post from 1999 on his site.

Would solve *that* problem :)

If you want to stress how old the post is, you could say

> On his site, I found posts dated as far back as 1999.
>   Some posts on his site go back as far as 1999.

Comment: Wow that was fast :) Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: how did you change from *that* to *his*? I'm curious! :)

Comment: Creativity, @MaulikV :) Or simply not reading the exact example perfectly :D

Comment: @oerkelens lol...+1 i'm really laughing at this answer. Nice one! :)